# Issue with year selection when having two JQuery datepickers

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm having issues with getting the year selection drowdown to show up on my first datepicker. It just won't appear. Does anybody know how I can enable it? Here is my code:

```
<input id="dtFrom" type="text" class="date-picker" />
<input id="dtTo" type="text" class="date-picker2" />  

$(".date-picker").datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    minDate: new Date(2014, 1 - 1, 1)
});

$(".date-picker2").datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    minDate: new Date(2014, 1 - 1, 1)
});
```

Comment: Are you getting date picker or issue is with only the year dropdown?

Comment: yes, only the year dropdown, and on only one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the necessary imports at the header of your html?

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

In this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b5np5Lnm/) you can find a working example

Comment: I have all necessary imports.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make a call to jquery-ui?

this is your code with calling jquery-ui and it works fine

```js
 $(".date-picker").datepicker({
            showButtonPanel: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            minDate: new Date(2014, 1 - 1, 1),
        });

        $(".date-picker2").datepicker({
            showButtonPanel: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            minDate: new Date(2014, 1 - 1, 1),
        });
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id="dtFrom" type="text" class="date-picker" />
    <input id="dtTo" type="text" class="date-picker2" />
```

Comment: Yes, I did make a call to JQuery.

Comment: you need to call both jquery and jquery-ui, see this link https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: can you share the full code or maybe show the problem in jsfiddle

Comment: I figured it out. I'd called the datepicker constructor twice on the same element without realizing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason to be a change event. I don't know why this altered the behaviour of the datepicker even when it doesn't do anything, to be honest, but now I know the reason atleast.

```
$("body").on("change", ".dtFrom", function () {}
```

Edit:
If anyone knows why this was the reason, please let me know.